# Synchronizing Active TD with Boxes Above HTML Tables using MySQL Data

Tags: javascript, ajax

**Hello fellow developers,**

I'm new to backend development, working on a project with three HTML tables, each linked to its MySQL table. My aim is to synchronize the content of multiple boxes above the tables based on the active  element in each table. I'm unsure of the best approach for this.

**Project Overview:**

Three HTML tables, each displaying data from a corresponding MySQL table.
Multiple boxes above the tables.
When I activate or deactivate a  in any table, the boxes above should update to reflect the selected  data.

*Possible Solutions Considered:*

*Fetch All Data on Website Launch:* Fetching all MySQL data at launch and manipulating boxes based on the active  but unsure if this scales well.

*Update Boxes on TD Activation/Deactivation: *Send MySQL query each time I interact with tables to update the boxes, which could be cumbersome.

Looking for a simpler, more effective approach. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Why do you need to reach out to the backend if clicking on a GUI element updates another GUI element? Do you need to fetch additional data? If this is a scaling question, then I'm afraid you need to test both approaches as the devil is in the details.

Comment: I have a query  that selects records "WHERE Volany = '00421$clientNumber'" from the main table  while $clientNumber is all the  known numbers that I have written in  secondary mysql table, secondary table is also used to display mentioned tables with  $clientNumber and $clientOwner in the gui, and i want to somehow make so when I activate td in the gui, boxes will show only data related to activated numbers in the gui instead of all the numbers in secondary table

Comment: So I'm not sure if I should run a query every time I activate or deactivate line in  html table or collect all the data before, or something else that I can't  think of

Comment: Both are valid solutiins and we cannot tell you which one is better for your particular case. You need to make this call. What I would consider if I had to make this decision: how much additional do I need when I display the details vs the summary list and how likely is for details to change while I view the list and if it is a big problem if the details I show is outdated.

Comment: Well, you need to make the decision yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to test both of them then